# From Old French -iss into English -ish

Tags: english, language-change, old-french

I have read this information on the word *perish*:

"mid-13c., from *periss*- present participle stem of Old French *perir*"

And this comment is below a question of mine on English Language & Usage site:

"*accomplish* (from Old French *acompliss-*), *abolish* (from OF (*aboliss-*), *banish* (from OF *banniss-*), *replenish* (from OF *repleniss-*), *nourish* (from OF *norriss*-), and *finish* (from OF *feniss*-) underwent the same transformation, and there are probably more."

> How do you explain this transformation (transition) from OF *-iss* into English *-ish*?

Answer (score 4):

The OED has s.v. "-ish suffix 2":

> A suffix of verbs, representing French -iss-, extended stem of verbs
>   in -ir, e.g. périr to perish, periss-ant, ils periss-ent. The French
>   -iss- originated in the Latin -isc- of inceptive verbs, which in Italian, Provençal, and French was extended to form a class of simple
>   verbs, corresponding to Latin verbs in -īre and -ēre, and including
>   others which were assimilated to these. **At their first adoption, these
>   verbs ended in English in -is, -ise, -iss(e, which before 1400 changed
>   to -isshe.** In Scottish the original -is, -isse, was retained longer,
>   and appeared in 16th cent. as -eis(e: pereis, fleureis. Among the
>   chief examples of this ending are abolish, accomplish, banish,
>   blandish, blemish, brandish, burnish, cherish, demolish, embellish,
>   establish, finish, flourish, furbish, furnish, garnish, impoverish,
>   languish, nourish, perish, polish, punish, ravish, relinquish,
>   replenish, tarnish, vanish, varnish.   In some cases, other French
>   endings have been levelled under this suffix in Anglo-Norman or
>   English: such are admonish, astonish, diminish, distinguish, eternish,
>   famish, lavish, minish, monish, publish, relish, etc., for the history
>   of which see the individual words.In a few words the French -iss- is
>   represented in English by -ise, or even -ize: e.g. avertir, -iss-
>   advertise v., châstir, -iss- chastise v.; amortir, -iss- amortize v.;
>   réjouir, rejouiss- has given rejoice n.

No mention of Picard.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to palatalisation. The sound [ɪ], which is before [s] and has a place of articulation retracted in comparison to [s], triggered this sound change by forcing [s] to adopt the same place of articulation as [ɪ].

When this phenomenon appears, we call that assimilation, ie a sound will change in acquiring (a) feature(s) of another sound.

Comment: Maybe more correct to say that it *is* palatalisation, by we don't necessarily know why it happened here and not in app the other descendants of these words.

Comment: @Adam I don't understand your comment.

Comment: s/app/all.   Why did this happen in English but not in French, German or even (apparently) Scots?

Comment: @Adam See the fdb's answer for temporal explanations. In addition, each language has its phonological rules and evolves according to its own rules.